# Visual Studio installer project version as beta

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I wanted to add a beta tag to the version number of my visual studio installer project. I tried to set the version property to '1.0.0-beta' but the generates a build error.

> ERROR: Invalid product version '1.0.0-beta'. Must be of format '##.##.####'

Is there an other way to indicate that the program is in a beta version or to overrule the format check? What is the way this is supposed to be done?

Comment: There is no way. Usually people store words like "Beta" in product name.

Comment: Why not just change the name of the compiled MSI and put "beta" in the file name? Maybe that happens auto-magically if you do as Lex Li suggests? I can't recall.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Ill just put it in the filename then.